# Как вычислить площадь поверхности арочного ангара?

Tags: математика, геометрия, формулы

Как вычислить площадь поверхности всего арочного ангара (площадь всех сторон)?

Дается:

- высота фиксированная 8 метров;
- ширина меняется от 10 до 100 метров;
- длина меняется от 10 до 100 метров;

Какая будет формула?

Пример ангара:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Осталась мелочь — форма ангара :)

Comment: Давайте вы определите ее не как архитектор, а как математик. Изобразите чертеж с размерами, и этого будет достаточно.

Comment: Добавил схему )

Comment: Можно принять что торец -полукруг, или форма сложнее?

Comment: Если предположить что профиль всегда окружность, то по трём точкам она однозначно находится. Дальше находим длину дуги и умножаем на длину ангара. Для боковых частей находим площать сегмента. Все формулы есть в учебнике по геометрии

Comment: Торец не полукруг.

Comment: При ширине в 100 метров и высоте 8 — что собой представляет передняя сторона? Эллипс? Если нет - то что именно? пока данных маловато. Но это 2 площади торцов + длина дуги торца, умноженная на длину ангара, плюс (если надо учитывать и дно) ширина, умноженная на длину.

Comment: При ширине в 100 метров и высоте 8 - полуЭллипс получается да. Дно не учитываем.

Comment: Голосую за закрытие. По сути, предлагается самим описать задачу.

Comment: Что-то я сильно сомневаюсь что там эллипс. Для него вообще-то нет формулы вычисления длины дуги. Скорее имеется в виду сегмент круга.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разбиваем ангар на составные части и ищем их площади. Не понимаю в чем тут сложность?

1. Находите приближенный периметр эллипса (торца). Например по вот такой формуле P = 2π√(A^2+B^2)/8. Или ищете более точную, не суть важно.
2. Делите пополам (у вас торец - половинка эллипса, по вашим словам)
3. Умножаете длину периметра на длину ангара - вот крыша
4. Добавляете площади торцов
5. Всё..

Comment: Находите периметр эллипса это хорошая шутка.  Только этот интеграл не берётся.

Comment: @AlexeyTen пусть будет приближенный. Что скажете?

Comment: Ну я примерно то же написал в комментарии, только принял торец за сегмент круга. Тогда всё банально считается по формулам

Comment: Уже что то вырисовывается